# Fake "misplaced alignment tab character &" error!

Tags: errors

I made a mistake and added **&** without a slash to my bibliography, then I got the error **! Misplaced alignment tab character &.** However I deleted the whole entry that caused the error, but somehow the error keeps appearing.

Texmaker says the error is in line 368 but there is the end of my document (\end{document}).

Please help. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you rerun Biber after fixing the `.bib` file?

Comment: I deleted the `.aux` , `.bbl` and `.bcf` files and now Texmaker is able to generate the pdf again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what was needed was to rerun biber.  The author removed the interim files and fixed the problem, as noted in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly what is happening is a problem with your build sequence. It is most likely something like this:

- First run [xe|pdf]latex to generate updated biblatex input files.
- Second run biblatex to generate the citation list.
- Third, rerun [xe|pdf]latex to generate the final output.

The problem, then, is that the mistake has baked itself into the biblatex citation list that gets included in the document, and when you run xelatex or pdflatex, that is causing an error to be thrown, which aborts your build sequence. This means that biblatex is never rerun and the citation list is not regenerated with the error removed.

The solution is to delete the `.bbl` and `.bcf` files from the build directory so that they are not included in the initial run.